# How to solve : Login failed for user 'net'?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I want to connect SQL Server with JDBC:

```
 try{
     Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
     Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-T5SLVUB:16000;database=Netos_DB;user=net;password=net"); 
    // gets a new connection
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      out.println("Driver Error" );
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      out.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

but I get this error in my page (which means that I have a problem in my url):

> SQLException: Échec de l'ouverture de session de l'utilisateur 'net'. ClientConnectionId:70747c93-1fdd-4506-8712-2ed99fb78527

PS: I'm sure that the Username and Password are correct and Server Name also.

[image: This is my connection informations]

Comment: In your connection you type `"saa"` instead of `"sa"`. and the error mention `"sa"`Are you sure about that?

Comment: Using the SA account is a bad idea for an application; create a `LOGIN` and `USER` with appropriate permissions. As for the error, I suggest checking the logs, but create the new credentials first and try that.

Comment: Nice spot @Sami , though that would mean the error would say `'sa'` too. Unless the error and code aren't actually related.

Comment: Yeah, it makes me confused a bit @Larnu, you also gave a good info there although I always think that this is for a test only. But still they shouldn't use the sa account.

Comment: @Larnu i renamed the sa login saa in my sql but nothing happens is there any configuration i should do ??

Comment: Did you try to login via SSMS with User: sa Pwd: 123? If so please provide the whole error Msg @imanealami

Comment: @Sami yes i did and i can connect with success .really i dont know whats the problem.

Comment: @Sami also i connected with success using php so the only problem is with j2ee

Comment: I'm not saying rename that account, I'm saying *don't use it*. You don't mention the logs I asked you to check either. What did they say, edit your question to include them.

Comment: You're doing so many wrong things out there @imanealami. First you should't use the `sa` account, and you shouldn't rename it too, instead as Larnu suggest, you should create a login. With the few info in hands I can only imagine that the error because you type a wrong credentials.

Comment: Also, why you have `"jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-T5SLVUB\\SQL2008R2..."` instead of `"jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-T5SLVUB/SQL2008R2..."`? You didn't gave us enough info to go with for example the State of the error message. Thus why @Larnu ask for the logs

Comment: Since you are specifying  port number, you can omit the instance name like `jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-T5SLVUB:16000`

Comment: Hi @DanGuzman thks for information ,but problem still exist ,i created a new login and it's giving me the same error!!! pleaaaaaase help guys

Comment: Check the SQL Server error log. That may have more detailed information as to why the login failed.

Comment: Sorry but where can I find the SQL Server error log